# Return inserted row ID in wordpress wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want insert some data to a table of the wordpress then return it's auto increase id value.

I do this but both of these has error:

```
INSERT INTO wp_sho_app_form (job_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES(1, 'Caldwell', 'Estrada'); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

This code word well in MySql but by `$wpdb` I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1

I call this statement by `$wpdb->query` and also `$wpdb->get_results`, but both of them has that error. 
I don't want use `$wpdb->insert` for some reasons and I should use this type of code.

Answer (score 4):

The correct way is to use `insert_id`.

```
$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;
```

if your make another query its not consistent if you have new entries and a lot of traffic. That can cause wired problems.

And that is only working after insert and you should use them. Don't fight the framework.

Comment: Thanks alot, but as I wrote I can't use insert method. Because I gather some data from $_POST which I send all of them to a insert method in my own ORM system. When I use insert mthod of wpdb because there are some extra field than table columns this method has error for those extra fields.

Comment: On the otherhand I sould do something like transaction including some update and insert which are related together. So I need run this type of scripts.

Comment: Try to run that line after your query. Perhaps its working.

Comment: And if I have multi insert update and a some select in my query? Your answer weill work with single query. And I must have a exactly an object which maped to my table. Otherwise it can't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a custom query then another to select the last item in the table. If you are using a stand alone php file you need to include the wp-load.php file to get the wordpress functions.

```
$query = "
    INSERT 
    INTO wp_sho_app_form 
    (job_id, first_name, last_name) 
    VALUES
    (1, 'Caldwell', 'Estrada')
";
$wpdb->query($query);
$query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM wp_sho_app_form 
    ORDER BY col_id desc  
    LIMIT 1
";
$wpdb->query($query);
```

Comment: That can cause a lot of raise condition problems if you have a lot of traffic. Between your both queries it's possible that another user make an insert. Then your don't get the ID from your inserted entry.

Comment: @Christopher as Stony wrote this can cause problem on same time inserting and it cause alot of  extra query to database!

Comment: I agree with stony, i myself would work with in the framework.  Im just proving a point of testing. On a large scale there will definitely be issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do multiple query by wpdb. The solution which I could find lastly is using direclty MySqli. I wrote this two function for do it. May be it be useful for sombody. As in ajax wordpress not load so I check to find **wp-config** fle to get details of connection at first:

```
public static function run_query($query)
    {
        $wp_config_path = script_generator::get_wp_config_path();
        if($wp_config_path == null){
            echo 'Could not found wp_config file!';
            return;
        }
        require_once $wp_config_path;
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        $result_count = 0;
        $result_set = array();
        if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
            do {
                $current_result_count = 0;
                $current_result = array();
                if ($result = $mysqli->use_result()) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                        $current_result[$current_result_count] = $row;
                        $current_result_count++;
                    }
                    $result->close();
                }
                $result_set[$result_count] = $current_result;
                if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
                    $result_count++;
                }
            } while ($mysqli->next_result());
        }

        /* close connection */
        $mysqli->close();

        return $result_set;
    }

    function get_wp_config_path(){
        $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
        do {
            if( file_exists($dir."/wp-config.php") ) {
                return $dir."/wp-config.php";
            }
        } while( $dir = realpath("$dir/..") );
        return null;

    }
```